# How to convert a csv file, that has array data, into a json file?

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv

I have a CSV file with a bunch of columns. 
A few of the columns are the same, but I want to convert them to a JSON object where they all live under the same array.

For example in the CSV:

```
firstname,lastname,pet,pet,pet
Joe, Dimaggio, dog, cat
Pete, Rose, turtle, cat
Jackie, Robinson, dog
```

I want the JSON to be

```
{ firstname: Joe,
  lastname: Dimaggio,
  pets: ["dog", "cat"]
},
{ firstname: Pete,
  lastname: Rose,
  pets: ["turtle", "cat"]
},
{ firstname: Jackie,
  lastname: Robinson,
  pets: ["dog"]
}
```

I'm trying to write a simple Python script to do this but I'm running into problems.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('userdata.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('userdata.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("firstname", "lastname", "pet", "pet", "pet");
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
record = {}
for row in reader:
    record['firstname'] = row['firstname']
    record['lastname'] = row['lastname']
    record['pets'] = json.JSONEncoder().encode({"pets": [row['pet'], row['pet'], row['pet'], row['pet'], row['pet']]});
    json.dump(record, jsonfile, indent=4)
    ##json.dump(json.loads(json.JSONEncoder(record)), jsonfile, indent=4)
print "something worked"
```

But this is acting funny since it's printing `pets` as an array inside an object called `pets`.

I can't figure out how to get the array `pets` outside the object `pets. Also it's adding backslashes to the array items

```
{
    "firstname": "Joe",
    "lastname": "Dimaggio", 
    "pets": "{\"pets\": [\"dog\", \"cat\"]}"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because you are encoding it and then using `json.dumps` which is basically encoding it twice. Remove `json.JSONEncoder().encode(...)` and it should work correctly.

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('userdata.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('userdata.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("firstname", "lastname", "pet", "pet", "pet");
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
record = {}
for row in reader:
    record['firstname'] = row['firstname']
    record['lastname'] = row['lastname']
    record['pets'] = [[row['pet'], row['pet'], row['pet'], row['pet'], row['pet']]
    # Remove blank entries
    record['pets'] = [x for x in record['pets'] if x is not '']
    json.dumps(record, jsonfile, indent=4)
print "something worked"
```

The backslashes you saw were from escaping the json string, a result of serializing it twice.

Comment: ah awesome. So if JSON.dumps encodes it, what's the point of having another encode?

Comment: I believe `json.dumps` is simply a function that uses the `JSONEncoder` class behind the scenes. In this case, you only needed to use one to get the job done.

Comment: also since it's just a minor question, can you edit in your answer how I can avoid the `pet` columns that are blank? I don't want to get in my array `pets: ["dog", "", ""]`. I just want it to have `"dog"`

Comment: Yep! `record['pets'] = [x for x in record['pets'] if x is not '']`